# The value of the slider would not change when only pushed the pips when using Jquery UI slider pips

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

there is the issue with me .

For example, the slider10 in http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/
When push on the slider, both the value of the slider and the value of the pips will change.

But, if only pushed on the pips(in this example,months), the value of pips(months) changed but the value of the slider didn't change althoug the positon of the button which is on the slider had changed.

here is my code:
http//jsfiddle.net/si22si22/2m5Np/1/

I guess maybe the "ui.value" can not get the value of slider without be slided?

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you mean the value under the answer should reflect the location of the cursor ? eg : b , when the cursor is at loc 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si22si.

http://jsfiddle.net/2m5Np/7/
^^ Please view that, and note that the slider-pips plugin only triggers a `slidechange` and not a `slide` when a pip is clicked on (purposefully) :)

```
var pse = ["a","b","c","d","e","f", "g"];
var initValue = 0;

$("#slider")

  .slider({ 
    max: 3, 
    min: -3, 
    step: 1,
    value: initValue
  })

  .slider("pips" , {
    rest: "label" , 
    labels: pse
  })

  .on("slidechange slide", function( event, ui ) {

    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );

  });

$( "#amount" ).val( initValue );
```

Note the slight change in format too, that is my preference because it stops you repeating code in the "slidechange" and "slide" events. I also chose not to simply `trigger` a `slidechange` after init, this is because the slider plugin (jQuery) seems not to return the `ui` object when you trigger the `slidechange` event immediately :/

hope this helps, mate!

Comment: Dear simeydotme
Thanks a lot!
I have learned a lot from this issue.